# How can I send a POST request within a Laravel app using HTTP Client?

Tags: php, laravel, http

I would like to send a POST request to my post route in the same app using the Laravel HTTP Facade. Unfortunately, I'm getting an error.

> cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 30001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for http://localhost/receive

When I address the route with Postman, everything works correctly.
Why is this happening?

I am using Laravel 10.

Here is my code very simplified:

sending route:

```
Route::get('/send', function () {

   $response = Http::withOptions([
       'verify' => false
   ])->post('http://localhost/receive', [
       'title' => 'My Title',
       'body' => 'My Body Content',
   ]);

   return $response->successful();
});
```

and receiving route:

```
Route::post('/receive', function(Request $request) {
    $title = $request->input('title');
    $body = $request->input('body');

    // necessary logic here...

    return response()->json(['message' => 'Success']);
});
```

Hitting the /receive endpoint with postman.
[image]

I've also excluded the endpoint from CSRF verfication in Laravel VerifyCsrfToken Middleware.

Inside the LAravel Sail container i tried also this:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "title": "foo",
  "body": "bar"
}' http://localhost/api/receive
```

I've also replace the localhost with the ip 127.0.0.1.

and the response was ok!

[image]

What am I missing?

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
   
    protected $except = [
        '/receive'
    ];
}
```

Comment: Are you using Docker for development?

Comment: yes - Laravel Sail

Comment: Go inside the container and try to call the URL using curl and see what happens. Also, try to replace it with 127.0.0.1 in the request.

Comment: Are you making this request "anonymously", or are you sending any credentials? (If you are sending the current session ID, this could be an issue with session locking.)

Comment: in bash i tried this `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "title": "foo",
  "body": "bar"
}' http://localhost/api/receive` and im gettint the correct response. Also the 127.0.01 is working correctly.

Comment: i try to hit the endpoint without any credentials. I actually wanted to keep it as simple as possible, but it looks like it might be more difficult.

Comment: @GregOstry Also check what's in the TrustProxies middleware as this is Laravel. Very limited  experience with Sail , but I guess you need to publish the site,  with ```sail share ```command

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside the actual error you're asking about, we should actually go back a step...why is one function in your application sending a HTTP request to another function in the *same* application?? It doesn't seem to make a lot of sense.

There is a bit in the receiving route code where you wrote `// necessary logic here...` ...if you separate that off into a function in another class, then *both* routes can call that function directly when they need it, without the need for the overhead and complication of extra HTTP requests.

Comment: The '/receive' route is just for testing. The route will then live in another app.

Comment: Well the error you have got is about calling that specific URL and a timeout. So it's not a problem you'd necessarily have if you genuinely had another app. Why not make a simple other app to test with more realistically?